# NDEF_DISCOVERED doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, galaxy, ndef

I have a problem which I find realy strange.
I have an application which should start when a tag containing an NdefMessage is scanned.
This all works fine on the Galaxy Nexus, the Nexus S and the HTC one X but when I try to do this on the Galaxy S3 the application doesn't come up.

My intentfilter looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

This should show the application in the app chooser every time a tag is scanned which contains a NdefMessage.
Now to solve this on the Galaxy S3 I need to add TAG_DISCOVERED. But this isn't what I want because now it popsup with EVERY tag I scan.

Has anybody else seen this behaviour?

Edit:

It also contains the TECH_DISCOVERED intentfilter which also checks for the ndef technology so this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Galaxy S3 here and it receives NDEF_DISCOVERED ok.

Try looking if you have another application that has registered the same intent, and has default redirection of that intent to it.

Comment: Hello noni,
Thanks for your reply, I've found out why the NDEF_DISCOVERED doesn't work. It is because I don't use a mimeType See the following line:
<data android:mimeType="specific mimetype"/>

The reason I don't do that is because I want the application to start with every ndefmessage and not only a ndefmessage which contains a specific mimetype.

only didn't find out how to solve it.